# Prove⌈a/b⌉ ≤ a/b + (b-1)/b

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For integers $a, b > 0$,

Prove $⌈a/b⌉ ≤ (a + (b-1))/b$

RHS $= a/b + (b-1)/b $ where $ (b-1)/b $ is $[0,1)$

If $a/b$ is an integer, inequality holds true as we are adding non-negative term.

If $a/b$ is not an integer, $⌈a/b⌉ < (a/b) + 1$    -- Equation 1

How to demonstrate that switching 1 with some smaller number $(b-1)/b$ leads to the $<$ transforming to $≤$ in equation 1.

Similarly, prove $⌊a/b⌋ ≥ (a - (b-1))/b$

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ both (positive) *integers?*

Comment: yes, fixed the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note $\left\lceil\dfrac{a}{b}\right\rceil=\dfrac{a}{b}+1-\left\{\dfrac{a}{b}\right\}$, where $\{\}$ is the fractional part of the number. So the question reduces to $$1-\left\{\dfrac{a}{b}\right\}\le\dfrac{b-1}{b}\iff \left\{\dfrac{a}{b}\right\}\ge\dfrac{1}{b}$$
This is so obvious. In case you don't know, then

> Suppose $(a,b)=1$, then $\left\{\dfrac{a}{b}\right\}$ must be a fraction with denominator $b$. Now suppose $(a,b)>1$, then the fraction part is a fraction with denominator $d:=\dfrac{b}{(a,b)}$. Then it must be at least $\dfrac{1}{d}\ge\dfrac{1}{b}$.

Comment: the notation of ceiling(a/b) in terms of fractional part is very helpful and makes intuitive understanding of inequality easier. the fraction part is a/b remainder divided by b where remainder is >= 1 when a/b is not an integer. so {a/b} >= 1/b always.

Comment: this answers makes it clear that both inequalities in the question are rooted in the fact that remainder of a/b is such that 1<= remainder <= (b-1). The case for remainder = 0 can be dealt separately.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, that's not a good approach for it.

Instead: write $a=qb+r$ with $0\leq r\lt b$. Then
$$\left\lceil\frac{a}{b}\right\rceil = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
q &\text{if }r=0,\\
q+1 &\text{if }r\gt 0.
\end{array}\right.$$
The case "if $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer is the case $r=0$ and you are fine. In the second case, note that
$$\left\lceil\frac{a}{b}\right\rceil = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b-r}{b}.$$
Go from there.

Or you can deal with both cases simultaneously by just considering $\frac{a+(b-r)}{b}$.

Do something similar for $\left\lfloor \frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor$.

---

If $a$ and $b$ are *not* positive **integers**, then it is false. Take $a=0.1$, $b=0.2$. Then $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\left\lceil\frac{a}{b}\right\rceil = 1$. But
$$\frac{a+(b-1)}{b} = \frac{0.3-1}{0.1} = -\frac{.7}{.1} = -7,$$
and $1$ is not less than or equal to $-7$.

Answer (score 4):

$\lceil a/b \rceil$ is strictly less than $a/b+1$ and $b$ is positive, so that
$$
 b \left\lceil \frac ab \right\rceil < b \left( \frac ab + 1\right) = a + b \, .
$$
The expressions on the left and on the right are both *integers,* and two distinct integers differ by at least $1$. It follows that
$$
 b \left\lceil \frac ab \right\rceil \le  a + b - 1 \, ,
$$
which is the desired inequality.